# Array of Objects in Core Data Entity?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, entity

I've got two entities, one named exercise and the other named workout. I would like to store several different exercises in each workout object.

What is the correct logic here? Create an array of exercises in each workout?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't create arrays in Core Data. You can simulate them, however, using To-Many Relationships. Add a relationship to your `Workout` entity called, say, `exercises`. Then set its Destination to the `Exercise` entity and check the "To-Many Relationship" checkbox. Note that the exercises will be stored as an `NSSet`, not an `NSArray`, so they will not be ordered. If you want them to be in a specific order, I would recommend using the [`BWOrderedManagedObject`](http://www.fatcatsoftware.com/comments/per-object_ordered_relationships_using_core_data) subclass.

Comment: Since iOS 5, it is possible to sort the relationship. Just tick the checkbox "ordered" on the relationship in the editor.

Comment: Thanks for this great, 10 yr old explanation, @SteveHarrison!

Answer (score 7):

As the (still perfect) decade old answer of @SteveHarrison explains, you just click for "relationship", but do select "to-many"

[image]

so, some entity has many "Reply" items.  (I put "CD" in front of all entity names, hence, "CDReply".)

After you next rebuild, for free, you get

[image]

hence, say you have one of your `CDPost` which is `p`

The code is this simple

```
for oneJsonReply in yourJson {
    r = CDReply.your code to convert ( oneJsonReply ) to a CDReply
    p.addToReplys( r )
```