# Adding An Item To An NSSet For A Core Data One To Many Relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2

I have a core data relationship where one entity holds many of another entity. As far as I am aware each instance of the many class is held inside an NSSet? inside the one class. (?)

My question is - what is the best way to add items to this set? I figure this must be a very common problem - but I cannot seem to find an easy method.

This is my attempt: (This is all taken from the one class)

```
static var timeSlotItems: NSSet? //The Set that holds the many?


...



static func saveTimeSlot(timeSlot: TimeSlot) { //TimeSlot is the many object
    retrieveValues()
    var timeSlotArray = Array(self.timeSlotItems!)
    timeSlotArray.append(timeSlot)
    var setTimeSlotItems = Set(timeSlotArray)
    self.timeSlotItems = setTimeSlotItems // This is the error line

}
```

Where retrieveValues() just updates all the coreData values in the class.
TimeSlot is the many object which I want to add.

I get an error on the last line, the error is: "cannot invoke initializer for type Set<_> with an argument of list of type Array"

Am I conceptually wrong at all? Thanks!

Comment: One-to-many or many-to-many?

Comment: static function and self?

Answer (score 15):

For one-to-many this is easy. Just use the reverse to-one relationship.

```
timeSlot.item = self
```

For many-to-many I use this convenience method:

```
// Support adding to many-to-many relationships

extension NSManagedObject {
    func addObject(value: NSManagedObject, forKey key: String) {
        let items = self.mutableSetValueForKey(key)
        items.addObject(value)
    }

    func removeObject(value: NSManagedObject, forKey key: String) {
        let items = self.mutableSetValueForKey(key)
        items.removeObject(value)
    }
}
```

which is used like this:

```
self.addObject(slot, forKey:"timeSlotItems")
```

Comment: it's actually even easier now

Answer (score 15):

## Nowadays it is this easy...

For a to-many item named say "Reply", CoreData knows to add a call "addToReplys".

Hence...

```
p = one Post. your core data Post items have many core data Reply items.

for jr in yourJson {
    r = convert jr to a core data Reply
    
    p.addToReplys( r )
```

so it's just

```
p.addToReplys( r )
```

[Full example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60118403/294884)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You've declared both `timeSlotItems` and `saveTimeSlot:` as static, so I'm not sure what your intention is there. I suspect it's not what you need.

In the same way that Core Data automatically runtime-generates optimized accessors for attributes, it also generates accessors for relations.

You don't say what the name of the "one" side of the to-many relation is, but if I assume that it's something like `Schedule`, where `Schedule` has a to-many relation to `TimeSlot` called `timeSlotItems`, then Core Data will runtime-generate the following accessors for you:

```
class Schedule: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var timeSlotItems: Set<TimeSlot>
    @NSManaged public func addTimeSlotItemsObject(value: TimeSlot)
    @NSManaged public func removeTimeSlotItemsObject(value: TimeSlot)
    @NSManaged public func addTimeSlotItems(values: Set<TimeSlot>)
    @NSManaged public func removeTimeSlotItems(values: Set<TimeSlot>)
}
```

Comment: I made them both static because this class is essentially the class of global values used throughout the app - everything in that class is static - I should have clarified, sorry!

Comment: @DaleBaker Global variables, global managed objects, a global managed object context... while you may think you need them, they're never a good solution, and they will lead to more problems than they "solve" for you.  At some point, you'll desire to use a scratch context, or do something off the main thread, or mock, and find it difficult or impossible to test or encapsulate your code, because everything is needlessly tightly coupled.

Comment: @TrevorSquires Actually, I think that you can use the `insert` and `remove` methods of the `Set` directly.